# Sending file in chunk always crashes at 10th chunk

Tags: ruby

I have a strange problem with my ultra-simple method. It sends a file in 4MB chunks to foreign API. The thing is, always at 10th chunk, foreign API crashes.

It's impossible to debug the API error but it says: `The specified blob or block content is invalid` (That API is Azure Storage API but it's not important right now, the problems lays clearly on my side).

Because it crashes at 10th element (which is 40th megabite) it's a pain to test it and debugging it "by hand" takes a lot of time (partly in cause of my bad internet connection speed) i decided to share my method

```
def upload_chunk()
  file_to_send = File.open('file.mp4', 'rb')

  until file_to_send.eof?
    @content = file_to_send.read 4194304 # Get 4MB chunk
    upload_to_api(@content) # Line that produces the error
  end
end
```

Can you see anything, that can be wrong with this code? Please have in mind that it ALWAYS crashes at 10th time and works perfectly for files of size lesser than 40 MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a search for `ruby "The specified blob or block content is invalid"` and found this as the second link (first was this page):

http://cloud.dzone.com/articles/azure-blob-storage-specified

This contains:

> If you’re uploading blobs by splitting blobs into blocks and you get the above mentioned error, **ensure that your block ids of your blocks are of same length.** If the block ids of your blocks are of different length, you’ll get this error.

So my first guess is that the call to `upload_to_api` is assigning ids from 1-9, then when it goes to 10 the id length increases causing the problem.

If you don't have control over how the ids are generated, then perhaps you can set the amount of bytes read on each iteration to be no more than 1/9 of the total file size.

Comment: Oh my god, i can't describe how dumb i feel right now. I preassumed that it's something wrong with cutting a file to chunks process and didn't even checked what that error exactly means. BIG THANKS Matt !